# Popup window inside php code

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, popup

I'm trying to do table where pressing on ID, it opens popup window, where will be menu, for example, change row values, add comments.. 
But I have a problem with generating link for each row:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
// Each $row is a row from the query
$rowid = $row->ID;
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open("http://192.168.210.140/todolist/controls-menu?funnelid="'.$rowid.',"Controls Menu","width= 700,height= 500,toolbar= no,location= no,directories= 0,status= no,menuBar= no,scrollBars= no,resizable= yes,left= 400,top= 150,screenX= 400,screenY= 150");">'.$rowid.'</a>';
```

Maybe it's need to add

```
<script type="text/javascript>
... Some script when pressing <a href="#">
</script>
```

But I have no idea, how to detect from script which link is pressed, for example is it

```
http://192.168.210.140/todolist/controls-menu?funnelid=999
```

OR

```
http://192.168.210.140/todolist/controls-menu?funnelid=1100
```

**P.S. I'm using Wordpress.**

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having?  It is not clear from your post.

Comment: Be careful with those quotation marks in your `a` element: `onclick="javascript:window.open("http...` closes the `onclick` section right after the opening bracket!

Comment: Problem is that, it's not working on click

Comment: @AlexIL as @Hexaholic says the problem is with your `a` tag quotations, you are placing `"` inside of `"` for onclick value. If we won't use proper quotations, then the `a` tag output will not come as expected. Use escape characters, `onclick="javascript:window.open(\`http....`

Comment: can you please help me to write right quotations in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML Code

```
<?php  $id=1;?>
<a href="" onClick="popitup('popup1.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>')">Open</a>
```

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: But I can't do simple Html code, because I have php loop there to show the table.
I can only use echo '<a href=...</a>';

Comment: You can call function inside anchor tag. Try it.